# What's diff between paches and plugins

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I change the code in repo carbon-apimgt, and i run command "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" , I get a jar from target, what's next to apply this change?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins directory is where we keep all the jars of components that are used in the product. Patches directory is used to track the changes done to each jar. What it does is, when you add a directory (eg: patch0001/) and add a jar to this new directory (eg: `patch0001/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api_9.0.174.jar`), this will replace the same-named jar that is found in the plugins directory.

Before this replacement, the server will first backup all the jars that are found in the plugins directory to a new folder `patch0000` inside the patch folder.
At each startup, server will first apply the jars in the `patch0000` directory and start replacing the jars by increasing the counter of each patch folder. (eg: patch0000, then patch0001, patch0002 up to patch9999).

This is the difference between the plugins directory and patch directory. If you replace a jar in the plugins directory, this is not a backward compatible change. However, if you replace a jar using this patch mechanism, whenever you remove the `patch0001` directory from the system, this change will be reverted and the original jar will be preserved.